# Ignore everything expect all subfolders / files in .gitignore

Tags: eclipse, git

I want to allow all files (and their parent folder) within a specific directory of my eclipse project.

I want to allow all files within the *libs* folder

Example

```
RootFolder
    EclipseProjects
        ProjectOne
            build
            src
            WebContent
            libs
                lib1
                    file.jar
                    file1.jar
                lib2
                    file3.jar
                    file4.jar
                    etc.jar
```

In the root of git I have my .gitignore, which includes many variations on the same folder/files

I'm trying to just allow the jars to see if that will work too.

```
#Relevant lines of .gitignore
#Ignore
*.jar

#Allow
!libs/
!libs/*
!libs/*/*
!libs/**.jar
!/libs/
!/libs/*
!/libs/*/*
!/libs/**.jar
!libs/lib/*.jar
```

I cannot get this to work, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
!**/libs/**/*
```